# Codechef long challenge

Tags: c++

Q-You are given an integer N. Consider the sequence containing the integers 1,2,…,N in increasing order (each exactly once). Find the length of the longest subarray in this sequence such that the bitwise AND of all elements in the subarray is positive.

i tried the following code to solve the problem but it is not working can anyone tell why or give a test case where it fails

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int t,n,i,c;

   cin>>t;

   while (t--)
   {
       i = 1;
       cin>>n;

       while(i)
       {
           if(pow(2,i)<n)
           {
               i++;
           }
           else if (pow(2,i)==n)
           {
               break;
           }
           else
           {
               i--;
               break;
           }
       }
      
       if(n-pow(2,i)+1>pow(2,i)-pow(2,i-1))
       {          
           cout<<n-pow(2,i)+1<<endl;
       }
       else{
           cout<<pow(2,i)/2<<endl;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Obligatory: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10077)

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly?

Comment: All those `pow(2,i)` are unlikely to be a good idea. Could you explain what your algorithm is supposed to do?

Comment: not passing all test cases

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. That includes example input that reproduces the problem, the observed output, and the output desired instead. Also, stop using `pow` to generate powers of two. Some `pow` implementations are badly implemented and return inexact results for powers of integers. Use shifts for powers of two.

Comment: i think the problem is in algorithm

Comment: @Bob__: The algorithm finds the largest power of two, 2^i, such that 2^i ≤ n. Then there are two candidate subsequences: All the numbers from 2^i to n, inclusive (whose AND is non-zero because they share bit i) and all the numbers from 2^(i−1) to 2^i−1, inclusive (whose AND is non-zero because they share bit i-1). Any earlier subsequences are shorter because no subsequence can cross a power of two (because 2^p−1 AND 2^p is zero). Whichever of those has the larger length, n+1−2^i or 2^(i−1), is output. That should work, so an inaccurate `pow` implementation is a likely culprit.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @EricPostpischil Got it, but I'd aim to a slightly different [target](https://godbolt.org/z/ec3aszKPY), though.

Comment: FYI, the `pow(2, i)` can be replaced by a left shift: `(1<<i)`.  In many processor, the left shift is one instruction.  The `pow` function is at least two:  call and return.  The `pow` function is also floating point, so you may get some errors due to conversion between integers and floating point.

Comment: I recommend calculating `(1 << i)` (a.k.a. `pow(2,i)` once and placing into a temporary variable.  Some compilers may place this into a register and only calculate once (depending on the optimization level).

Answer (score 1):

Online judges like Codechef usually require the output to be *exactly* as expected, to validate a solution.

```
cout << n-pow(2,i)+1 << endl;
//        ^^^^^^^^ This returns a double.
```

In the previous line and the likes, the expression is evaluated as a `double` and printed with the standard format, so that a big enough value like e.g. `463129089` is printed in exponential format as `4.63129e+08`. That is unlikely the expected result.

You shouldn't have used `pow` in the first place. To calculate a simple<sup>1</sup> power of 2 you can just use bit shifting: `1u << i` is equal to 2<sup>i</sup>.

If C++20 is an option, you could write the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>  // std::max
#include <bit>        // std::bit_floor

int main()
{
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;

    while ( t-- )
    {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;

        auto floor = std::bit_floor(static_cast<unsigned>(n));
        std::cout << std::max(n - floor + 1, floor / 2) << '\n'; 
    }
}
```

---

(1) The constraints of the problem don't require a type bigger than 32-bit int, so there's no reason to switch to a floating-point type which could also introduce unwanted rounding errors.